# How do you run a Sveltekit application with ngrok in dev?

Tags: ngrok, sveltekit

I'm trying to use ngrok with Sveltekit's dev process.

This result in infinite reloads. I tried disabling hmr in `svelte.config.js`:

```
server: {
  hmr: false
}
```

Also tried to change port and host:

```
sever: {
  hmr: {
    clientPort: 443,
    host: <ngrok-host>
  }
}
```

But nothing helps - when visiting the client application it causes infinite reloads.

Comment: Did you restart your server between changes to `svelte.config.js`? Your second code block worked for me to prevent infinite refreshes (assuming you have `server` and not really `sever`)

Comment: Possible related vite issue: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/4259

Comment: Also, please share as precisely as possible the value for `host` — I found that including or excluding `https://` in the value here _does_ make a difference.